# How to use htaccess to redirect to a new domain with different url structure

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do a redirect from an old site to a new one:

OLD: blog.example.com
NEW: www.example.com/blog

To achieve the above, I got this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.exmaple.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bournemouth-datacentre/$ http://www.example.com/blog/
```

And that works fine. On top of that I need to redirect (example):

OLD: `blog.example.com/somecategory/some-title-here/`

NEW: `www.example.com/blog/some-title-here`

Note that I'm loosing the category in between domain and title and replacing it with blog. That's fine.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve both the subdomain to domain followed by blog redirect as well as the category redirects?

IMPORTANT: Old site is WP, new is Drupal!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(?:bournemouth-datacentre|general|london)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmaple.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. When I added and tried the following url: `http://blog.example.co.uk/bournemouth-datacentre/title/` I got `www.example.co.uk/blog/bournemouth-datacentre/title/`

Comment: That worked perfectly! And in order to add other categories in addition to `bournemouth-datacentre` (for instance, the categories are `bournemouth-datacentre`, `general`, `london`, etc. All to redirect to `/blog`? Shall I just add another `RewriteRule` underneath the first one?

Comment: see update answer for handling additional categories.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bournemouth-datacentre/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```